# Scanning a DynamoDB table using a filter expression with multiple possible comparison operators

Tags: python

**Context:** I am trying to perform a `scan()` on a DynamoDB table and apply some conditional operators to a filter expression. The operators however are passed in via AWS Lambda's event field. This means the operator is determined by an external user and my code needs to handle all possible cases. `conditionAPIParam` is what contains the passed in parameter.

**Current Solution:** I currently use an if conditional to compare the operator to a set constant and then construct different versions of the db scan() command based on which operator is used.

**Problem:** This means that I have to construct a different version of the command per operator that I support. This is extremely redundant and leads to a lot of repeated code.

**Question:** Is there any way I could utilize the same command but just swap the operator (e.g. `gt()`, `begins_with()`, `lt()`) based on the provided conditional?

**Code:**

```py
GREATER_THAN = "gt"
LESS_THAN = "lt"
EQUAL = "eq"
if conditionAPIParam == GREATER_THAN:
    query_response = table.scan(
        FilterExpression=Attr('Timestamp').gt(timestampAPIParam) & Attr('Rule').contains(ruleAPIParam) # The default rule param is '' which is a part of every string
    )
elif conditionAPIParam == LESS_THAN:
    query_response = table.scan(
        FilterExpression=Attr('Timestamp').lt(timestampAPIParam) & Attr('Rule').contains(ruleAPIParam)
)
elif conditionAPIParam == EQUAL:
    query_response = table.scan(
        FilterExpression=Attr('Timestamp').begins_with(timestampAPIParam) & Attr('Rule').contains(ruleAPIParam) # The default rule param is '' which is a part of every string
)
```

Comment: Can you indicate where `Attr` comes from? I've been unable to find documentation on it.

Comment: It comes from boto3: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/customizations/dynamodb.html#boto3.dynamodb.conditions.Attr

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you should simplify this. Make a dictionary whose key is any of the potential values for `conditionAPIParam`, and value is a non-bound class function reference.

```py
PARAMS = {
    'gt': Attr.gt,
    'lt': Attr.lt,
    'eq': Attr.begins_with,
}
query_response = table.scan(
    FilterExpression=PARAMS[conditionAPIParam](
        Attr('Timestamp'),  # self
        timestampAPIParam,
    ) & Attr('Rule').contains(ruleAPIParam)
)
```

With a non-bound reference, the first parameter must be `self`, which in all cases will be `Attr('Timestamp')`.

Comment: Interesting solution. Does this solution work because Python allows us to use functions as values to keys in a dict?

Comment: @Reinderien What would be the differences/pros/cons of using this approach vs getattr/methodcaller ?

Comment: @PrithviBoinpally Python allows us to use functions as values basically anywhere (not just in a dict)

Comment: @kubatucka This approach is simple and compatible with static analysis. A `getattr` approach defeats static analysis and will not benefit from e.g. IDE autocomplete.

Comment: @Reinderien That's probably true, but OP should also be aware that they could use `getattr(Attr('Timestamp'),conditionAPIParam)(timestampAPIParam)` and not need `PARAMS`.

Comment: @Teepeemm Not directly they can't. Note the difference between `eq` and `begins_with`.